# Launch application when battery saver is toggled windows 10

Tags: windows-10, laptop, battery

I would like to send a command to an application to pause itself eg - Wallpaper Engine when my battery saver kicks in but i could not find a way. Tried it with Task Scheduler but it only detect AC Power Plugged in/out.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure of when the feature was implemented into wallpaper engine, but there is an option within the settings to pause the current background when on battery now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).